# Is there a SQL way to find out the physical storage size of a table in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The underlying data source is stored in Parquet format and exposed through Hive.

Is there a way to use SQL query to ask the physical storage size of a given table?

Comment: why just not check summary files size (all files that belong to your table) at your storage layer (HDFS or S3)? I know Spark has some tools to check how much space dataset ocuppy in memory, but I don't think you can check FS usage from Spark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:
1) Check filesize of the underlying file . Ex: In HDFS use `hadoop fs -du -s <path>`
2) You can try using `describe formatted <table>;`